# Why doesn't Spider-Man want anyone to use his light switch?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home* Peter Parker has a sign in his bedroom taped over his light switch which reads:

> DO NOT TURN OFF

or words to that effect.

Is there any explanation anywhere as to why he doesn't want anyone to use that light switch?

Comment: He doesn't want anyone to turn off the dark?

Answer (score 11):

I believe the switch is connected to the device that contains the Iron Spider suit we see underneath it. It is therefore presumably keeping power to it so that the suit stays contained/charged inside of the device.

Comment: What makes you think it's connected to the suit?

Comment: @TheDarkLord I believe it was underneath the switch. I also read a few theories that thought the same as me but there is no evidence anywhere to this yet.

Comment: The suit was underneath the switch you mean? Not sure what you mean by "it was underneath the switch".

Comment: @TheDarkLord Yes I think it was but it has been about a week since I saw the film and obviously I can't fact check it at the moment.

Comment: I agree, saw the movie yesterday and the suit is sat in a case underneath the switch

Comment: @Bee Thanks for the confirmation that the suit was under the light switch, I did remember it being there but it's good having someone with a fresher viewing of it confirm my memory.

Comment: @Bee Was there are cable connecting it or something? Or did Stark have major infrastructure build into the walls? Just wondering how powering the suit would work. Maybe deserves a new question but maybe worth waiting til the DVD comes out so I can see a still.

Comment: @TheDarkLord The lightswitch in my room at home is connected to a plug socket, it's not hard to do and I feel like Stark could easily have rewired the cabling in the wall if Parker didn't already have it set up. I assume the suit just takes standard ampage to charge, otherwise it would be really inconvenient. Obviously neither me or Lethal are sure about this answer but it seems the best guess given the current facts. Feel free to post your theory if you have a better one! :)